# BeanShell PreProcessor (JMeter) - How can I generate a random future DateTime Stamp that covers current time out to 7 days?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I need assistance. I got some of this code off another site. It was randomly generating a date for the previous 7 days and randomly generating an hour and minute within a 24 hour period (any). I need the opposite of sorts. I need a random time that covers the current "now" time and goes forward 7 days but also requires the time (hour and minute) to be within a set hour range.

Requirements

1. Random Date covering current day ("now") and ahead one week (7 days).
2. Random Time generated; however time must fall between the hours of 1000hrs to 2200hrs and formatted as ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").

My BS PreProcessor Parameters I was passing for the below code are `(1 5 5)`. My dates seem to generate just fine but my time is only generating random hours as hours within the next 5 hours. How can I set a time range of 10am-10pm?

```java
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random; 

int minDay = Integer.parseInt(bsh.args[0]); // get first parameter minimal X Days ahead
int maxDay = Integer.parseInt(bsh.args[1]); // get second parameter maximal X Days ahead
int maxMinutesActivity = Integer.parseInt(bsh.args[2]); // get maximal duration of activity
int myThreadNum = 0;
int randomDay = 0; // RandomDays ahead
int minHour = 0;
int maxHour = 5;
int randomHour = 0;
int minMinute = 0;
int maxMinute = 60;
int randomMinute = 0;
int randomMinuteDuration = 0;
String formattedDate = "";

Random randomvar = new Random();
Date datevar = new Date();
Date datevarThisWeek = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
NumberFormat myFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
myFormat.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2); // required to have minimal two digits for Day, Hour, Minute

myThreadNum = ${__threadNum}; // just to show the thread number in debug
vars.put("myThreadNum",myFormat.format(myThreadNum));

randomDay = minDay+randomvar.nextInt(maxDay-minDay+1); // randomDays ahead between minDay and maxDay
datevar.setDate(datevar.getDate() - randomDay );
vars.put("randomDay",myFormat.format(randomDay));

randomHour = 1+randomvar.nextInt(maxHour-minHour+1); // randomHour ahead between minHour and maxHour
vars.put("randomHour",myFormat.format(randomHour));

randomMinute = minMinute+randomvar.nextInt(maxMinute-minMinute+1); // randomHour ahead between minMinute and maxMinute
vars.put("randomMinute",myFormat.format(randomMinute));

randomMinuteDuration = maxMinutesActivity; // randomduration between 1 and maxMinutesActivity
vars.put("randomMinuteDuration",myFormat.format(randomMinuteDuration));

// Calculate a Start and End time for this Week
randomDay = 1+randomvar.nextInt(5-1+1); // randomDays ahead this Week
datevarThisWeek.setDate(datevarThisWeek.getDate() + randomDay );

datevarThisWeek.setTime(datevarThisWeek.getTime() + ((randomMinute + (randomHour * 60 )) * 60 * 1000 ));
//datevarThisWeek.setTime(datevarThisWeek.getTime() + ((randomMinute + (randomHour * 60 )) * 60 * 1000 ) + myThreadNum );
formattedDate = df.format(datevarThisWeek);
vars.put("randomFireTime_FUTURE",formattedDate);

datevarThisWeek.setTime(datevarThisWeek.getTime() + (randomMinuteDuration * 60 * 1000 ));
//datevarThisWeek.setTime(datevarThisWeek.getTime() + (randomMinuteDuration * 60 * 1000 ) + myThreadNum );
formattedDate = df.format(datevarThisWeek);
vars.put("randomOrderTime_FUTURE",formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java fake library Might helps you.

```
import com.github.javafaker.Faker;

Date dob= faker.date().between(date1,date2);
```